# How to wrap text that is being typed in p tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple `contenteditable` `div` as an editor, and also have several buttons which allow the user to change the color of the text they had input by highlighting it and clicking the buttons.

Below is an example of one of the functions linked to the buttons:

```
        function yellow(){
    {       
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "yellow";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
    }
    }
```

As of now, the issue is that anything on the page that is being highlighted can be colored since I'm using `window.getSelection()`. I'm now trying to make it so only the text within my editor can be colored. I was thinking:

How can I improve the code such that any text that is being input into my editor is automatically wrapped in p tags? I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
function yellow(){
    {       
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.tagName != "p") return;
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        p.style.color = "yellow";
        p.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(p);
    }
    }
```

Comment: your editor must have some sort of class name. just check if the selection is in the div with the class name. class name must be unique.

Comment: Yes, the div has an id. I've tried checking if the selection is within that div, but the issue is after I've colored it, it no longer registers as part of the div, since it's now wrapped in span. Which means that I can no longer color it if it has already been colored.

Comment: nesting comes into place here. when you color it the newly created span should be nested inside the <div> tags of the editor, so that checking for the selection inside the editor still fires true

Comment: Could you provide some basic code for me to work with? I'm not too sure how nesting works.

Comment: Well you have to use your code from the lower field and change it to if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.className != "editor")  and now when you use your code only on text in the div with the editor class.